# How to send a image as response in flask

Tags: python, image, flask

How can I ssend a image as response in flask. I want whenever a user types **http://127.0.0.1:5000/showimg?url=https://example.com/favicon.ico** the response will be the urrl of GET param

```
@app.route('/showimg', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    urlToParse=request.args.get('url')
    #send img as resp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the image to a `base64` string and return the string. Then the front-end can convert it back to an image and show it. Something like this:

```
import base64

@app.route('/showimg', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    image_file = open(file, "rb")
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    return encoded_string
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to return the image in a html response --

```py
@app.route('/showimg', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return html('<img src="path/to/your_img.jpg" alt="your image">')
```